# PostgreSQL bouncing between extension does not exist and already exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have dumped my Supabase database into my local machine by using the following command:

```
pg_dump -Fc -U postgres "[DATABASE URL]" > database.dump
pg_restore -U postgres -d dump_test database.dump
```

When I try to create a new table that uses CITEXT extension I get the following error:

```
CREATE TABLE example_table (
    table_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    table_column CITEXT
);

ERROR:  type "citext" does not exist
```

Then, when I try to add CITEXT myself, I get this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS CITEXT;

NOTICE:  extension "citext" already exists, skipping
```

This is my search path:

```
 "$user", public
```

`\dx` returns:

| name | version | schema |
| --- | --- | --- |
| citext | 1.6 | extensions |
| pg_stat_statements | 1.9 | extensions |
| pgcrypto | 1.3 | extensions |
| plpgsql | 1.0 | pg_catalog |
| uuid-ossp | 1.1 | extensions |

**Version Info**

Supabase: "PostgreSQL 14.1 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 10.3.0, 64-bit"

Local: PostgreSQL 14.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit

pg_restore and pg_dump: 14.1

What is the reason behind this behavior and how can I create the table with the given extension?

Comment: 1) Version information, Superbase, Postgres being restored to, pg_dump and pg_restore. 2) Complete command line for pg_restore. 3) In new database using `psql`  what does `\dx` return?  **Add information as text** to question.

Comment: Pretty sure the issue is `citext` is installed in `extensions` schema. Either update the `search_path` to include the schema or schema qualify the type e.g. `extensions.citext`.

Comment: Or you could use [ALTER EXTENSION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterextension.html) to relocate it to another schema.

Comment: The error isn't that the *extension* doesn't exist, it is that the *type* doesn't exist.  And that is because the schema were the type can be found is not in your search_path.